# Probability that a vertex in graph chooses highest random value in neighbourhood

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I am studying distributed graph algorithms, and was unable to prove a seemingly straightforward claim. Following is the claim:

Every vertex, independently, chooses a random value (real number)  **r<sub>v</sub>**  in **[0,1]** . For a vertex **v** with degree **d<sub>v</sub>**, *probability* that it chooses the highest value in its neighbourhood, i.e. for all  **u** such that **(u,v) ∈ EDGES**  :  **r<sub>v</sub>  >  r<sub>u</sub>** , is exactly =

> 1/(d<sub>v</sub>+1) .

Comment: Are the random variables independent and the distribution is continuous?

Comment: @UjanGangopadhyay Yes, yes.,

Comment: Just say that the $d_v+1$ vertices are iid, no?

Comment: @caduk Sure, they are i.i.d

Comment: Yes, but now this is trivial, the probability that one of these is the greatest of all $d_v+1$ is the same for all, so in particular, for the $v$, it is $1/(d_v+1)$

Comment: @caduk I can see that why, but what would a formal proof look like? Also, does it matter if set of values r.v. can take is strictly finite?

Comment: It does not matter what the distribution of variables is as long as the variables are i.i.d. The multivariate distribution of a set of independent variables is described entirely by the marginals, so if you know your variables are independent, anything that you can compute for these variables can be deduced from the distribution of these variables while ignoring everything else.

Comment: @caduk Can you point to exact result which proves the claim in the question?

Comment: This is in fact the definition: The distribution factorize on the marginals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_random_variables (or you define it with the probability of an intersection is the product of probabilities, but you easily show this is equivalent)